# Kotlin native finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm follow a kotlin native tutorial [https://book.kotlincn.net/text/native-get-started.html](https://stackoverflow.com)
The code:

```
fun main() {
    val name = readln()
    name.replace(" ","").let {
        println("your name length is ${it.length}")
    }
}
```

When I run this,it outputs:
*Process 'command 'E:\codes\ktNative\build\bin\native\debugExecutable\ktNative.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3*

If I don't use the function *readln* like this:

```
fun main() {
    val name = "AAA  BBB CCC"
    name.replace(" ","").let {
        println("your name length is ${it.length}")
    }
}
```

Now it can run and output normally.

I want to know how to run normally with using the function *readln*.
I'm using Window10 x64 pro, IDEA2023, kotlin1.9.0, openjdk17.

Comment: How did you run this?

Comment: A typical use of exit code 3 on Windows is the C runtime `abort` function. It could be that the standard input is not defined. This could happen when some IDEs omit to set up standard input when running a program. I don't know if IntelliJ IDEA does this for Kotlin/Native, as I haven't used IDEA to create a Kotlin/Native project yet. I know that it works ok with Kotlin/JVM.

Comment: I tried 2 ways to run it.First,I just click the run button in the IDEA ide.Second,I open the output directory where the xxx.exe locates and double click the xxx.exe to run it.In the former way,it just directly exits with a code 3.But in the latter way,the xxx.exe runs well in a cmd window until I input the name and press enter button.

Comment: Oh，I just tried a new way to run it  and it works！In the output directory I right click, open a powershell window and execute "./xxx.exe".It now can receive my input and output the length of my input normally.